# Adding voids underneath analog signal for improved impedance matching

Tags: analog, pcb-design, impedance-matching

Using a snapshot of an eval board design below as an example, voids are added to the ground plane on layer 2 (green) right underneath the analog signal path on layer 1 (yellow). This causes the analog traces to reference the ground plane on layer 3 instead. I understand that this increases trace width, hence improved impedance matching and decreased signal loss at the trace-to-pad junctions.

What is the best way to determine the minimum width of the voids that guarantees that the signals do not reference layer 2? I assume this is based on the trace widths and the layer separations.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The "best" way is to build a board and measure the impedance. Another "best" way is to simulate it with some form of EM simulation software. The "quick" way is to use a rule of thumb like 5 tracewidths on either side (for microstrip). So, if your trace is 10 mils, keep all copper on layer 2 at 50 mils or more away.

However, that looks more like coplanar waveguide than microstrip...

Comment: The board thickness matters here too, copper on layer 2 should be relieved at least a couple of board thicknesses away from the signal trace.  I would say the real way is to simulate -- simply measuring the impedance won't easily tell you what fraction of the return current is in layer 2 vs 3.  So you should simulate to get the gap size, then measure the impedance and adjust the track width to hit your target.